# Set reference value for color range in viridis or RColorBrewer

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to make a plot using a color palette from packages `viridis` or `RColorBrewer`, but I would like to set what point in the variable distribution should be considered as the middle point in the color gradient.

For example, in the following plots, R takes 0.5 to be the middle point of the color range. How can I set a different value, for example, 0.25 ?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

# data
set.seed(1)
df <- expand.grid(x = 0:5, y = 0:5)
df$z <- runif(nrow(df))

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_distiller( palette="RdBu", guide = "colorbar")
```

[image]

```
# plot using viridis
library(viridis)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_viridis()
```

[image]

**EDIT**: I was looking for a solution similar to this one here, because the distribution of my variable is not symmetrical. However, I'd like to keep the entire color range from dark blue to dark red, which seems not to be possible.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, fill = z)) + geom_raster() +
  scale_fill_gradient2( low = "#2166ac", mid = "#f7f7f7", high = "#b2182b", midpoint = 0.2, 
                        space = "Lab", na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar")
```

[image]

Comment: @Henrik I've edited the question with more info.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try setting

```
 space = scale(c(-zlim, 0, zlim))
```

Where zlim is the extreme value of your data.